# Compile surprises when using a string as a template argument

Tags: c++, c++20

I was playing with strings in templates.  I read some interesting blogs and started playing with code.

In the next example, I was able to pass a string literal in a template argument:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template<size_t N>
struct StringLiteral {
    constexpr StringLiteral(const char (&str)[N]) {
        // commenting this makes the program to not compile
        std::copy_n(str, N, value);
    }
    constexpr size_t size() const
    {
        return N;
    }

    // changing N to literal, such as 10, makes the program to not compile
    char value[N];
};

template<StringLiteral lit>
void Print() {
    static constexpr auto size = lit.size();
    static constexpr auto contents = lit.value;

    std::cout << "Size: " << size << ", Contents: " << contents << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Print<"abc">();
}
```

[Godbolt Link](https://godbolt.org/z/6dE7cj5oK)

In this example, I'm passing a string to `Print` by a template parameter, and it will print the size and value.  So far so good.

However, I'm using some features that I don't fully understand, that's probably why I'm so confused.

1. If I remove `std::copy_n()`, it doesn't compile. That was very surprising because that code is inside the constructor, `N` was deduced just before, so I'm not sure why `copy_n` had these implications.
2. Changing `char value[N]` to `char value[10]` also makes the program invalid. 10 is a literal, so I was expecting the compiler would be able to deduce it without a problem.

Could you clarify what's going on?

Comment: I don't see errors there.

Comment: There is a small one :  `char value[N];` should be `char value[N] {};` the array must be initialized to be usable in a constexpr. Oh I see now blackcat also provides that as an answer

Comment: @PepijnKramer I'm mystified. Tested this with all available compilers and it doesn't produce any errors, is this a IFNDR case? Program compiles and runs. Except Intel one, which wants an explicit typecast. There is static analyzer's red line highlight, it's a Godbolt's feature and it doesn't go away with those fixes

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie OP's code is fine. They say they get errors after modifying it in a certain way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both errors are caused by `value` remaining partially uninitialized. Adding `{}` to zero all elements by default is one way to solve this: `char value[N]{};`.

Answer (score 4):

When you work with classes in a `constexpr` context, it is important to guarantee the initialization.

You don't need to set a value, but at least saying `: value()` will make it clear that the member is initialized:

```
constexpr StringLiteral(const char (&str)[N]) : value() {
        
}
```

---

If you leave the constructor empty without the `: value()`, you leave `value` uninitialized, which causes problems within the `constexpr` context.